# HAProxy connect to backend with source IP

Tags: http, tcp, load-balancing, haproxy

I am running HAProxy on a machine with multiple interfaces and I want the connection to the backend to be made from the source IP of the interface on which the client request came in. Using the source directive from the documentation in the listen blocks didn't seem to do it as all connections seem to come from the first interface. My configuration is as follows:

```
listen f_192.168.1.10_http
  bind 192.168.1.10:80
  source 192.168.1.10
  mode http
  option httplog
  capture request header Host len 30

  use_backend b_domain1_http if { hdr(host) -i domain1.com }

listen f_192.168.1.20_http
  bind 192.168.1.20:80
  source 192.168.1.20
  mode http
  option httplog
  capture request header Host len 30

  use_backend b_domain1_http if { hdr(host) -i domain1.com }

backend b_domain1_http
  mode http
  option httplog
  server srv1 domain1.com:80 check inter 30s
```

Ie. I am struggling to get connections coming in on interface 192.168.1.10 to have their source IP be 192.168.1.10 when connecting to the backend. Right now, regardless of if the connection comes in on 192.168.1.10 or 192.168.1.20, the outgoing connection to the backend is initiated from 192.168.1.10. I thought that using source in the listen would accomplish this but when I look at the output of netstat -at, all originating connections to the backend come from 1 interface.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can ensure the source ip of the connection to the backend is the same as the interface of the original client request?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use **source** as a parameter for a **server**.

```
backend be1
    ...
    server srv1 domain1.com:80 source ${frontend_ip} check inter 30s
```

I believe it is possible to substitute `%fi` for `${frontend_ip}`, and you may also use `%fp` or `${frontend_port}` to specifiy the port. This way you can remove the source statements in the frontends.

Comment: Hi, above option not working for me. Can you help me pls to fix the same issue ?